# In Perl is there a way to restart the program currently running from within itself?

Tags: perl, exit, subroutine

I am running a program in Perl that at one point evaluates data in an if statement called from within a subroutine, e.g.

```
sub check_good {
    if (!good) {
         # exit this subroutine
         # restart program
    } 
    else {
         # keep going
    }
} # end sub
```

The problem I have is with exiting and restarting. I know that I can just use `exit 0;` to exit straight out, but obviously this is not correct if I want to go back to the beginning. I tried calling the subroutine which essentially starts the program, but of course once it has run it will go back to this point again.
I thought about putting it in a while loop, but this would mean putting the whole file in the loop and it would be very impractical.

I don't actually know whether this is possible, so any input would be great.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have not changed `@ARGV`, or you keep a copy of it, you could possibly do something like [`exec($^X, $0, @ARGV)`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exec.html).

[`$^X` and `$0`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) (or `$EXECUTABLE_NAME` and `$PROGRAM_NAME`, see Brian's comment below) are the current perl interpreter and current perl script, respectively.

Comment: forgive my ignorance - I know that @ARGV is used for command line arguments, but I have used <STDIN> so can I assume that they store data in the same memory location (or something)?.

Comment: That's an assertion you could easily test.

Comment: If you consume stdin then you will have to buffer it yourself, perhaps in a temp file.

Comment: I would recommend using `^X` to ensure that the restarted process uses the same perl interpreter as the original script. i.e. something like `exec( ^X, $0, @ARGV)`.

Comment: +1 I never actually found myself with this requirement, but after reading the OP, this was my immediate thought as to a possible solution. Now I'm trying to imagine where I would find use for it! :)

Comment: And just for the sake of future maintainers, I generally recommend using the English versions of the "executable line noise" variables, a la - `exec($EXECUTABLE_NAME, $PROGRAM_NAME, @ARGV)`.  Just remember to `use English qw{ -no_match_vars }` or only pull in the variable names you specifically want to use to avoid a performance hit.  For the curious, that hit is described pretty succinctly in (http://search.cpan.org/~andk/Devel-SawAmpersand/lib/Devel/SawAmpersand.pm) and mentioned in the "Variables related to regular expressions" section of `perldoc perlvar`.

Comment: `exec( ^X, $0, @ARGV)` throws an insecure dependency error with `-T` on. How do we go about this in such a situation?

Comment: Okay figured it out. I did a regexp match to untaint it as the docs suggest. Smh.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative would be to always have two processes: A supervisor and a worker.

Refactor all your logic into a subroutine called `run`(or `main` or whatever). Whn your real logic detect that it needs to restart it should exit with a predefined non-zero exit code (like 1 for example).

Then your main script and supervisor would look like this:

```
if (my $worker = fork) {
    # child process
    run(@ARGV);
    exit 0;
}
# supervisor process
waitpid $worker;
my $status = ($? >> 8);

if ($status == 1) { ... restart .. }

exit $status; # propagate exit code...
```

In the simple scenario where you just want to restart once, this might be a bit overkill. But if you at any point need to be able to handle other error scenarios this method might be preferable.

For example if the exit code is 255, this indicates that the main script called die(). In this case you might want to implement some decision procedure wether to restart the script, ignore the error, or escalate the issue.

There are quite a few modules on CPAN implementing such supervisors. [Proc::Launcher](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Proc%3A%3ALauncher) is one of them and the manual page includes a extensive discussion of related works. (I have never used Proc::Launcher, it is mainly due to this discussion I'm linking to it)

Answer (score -1):

There's nothing to stop you calling `system` on yourself. Something like this (clearly in need of a tidy), where I pass in a command-line argument to prevent the code calling itself forever.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

print "Starting...\n";
sleep 5;

if (! @ARGV) {
        print "Start myself again...\n";
        system("./sleep.pl secondgo");
        print "...and die now\n";
        exit;
} elsif ((@ARGV) && $ARGV[0] eq "secondgo") {
        print "Just going to die straightaway this time\n";
        exit;
}
```

Comment: This solution depends on a pre-fixed filename. That starts to suck when we have multiple links or symlinks pointing to this script, under different names. And that is still assuming that no `chdir` was performed… Also, you are creating a whole cascade of processes. Calling yourself once won't matter, but restarting yourself this way 1000 times tends to fill the process table and RAM.

Comment: Agree with all those points, I was just trying to show that it is possible to re-start yourself. The answers below and above and clearly more comprehensive.